# suppf as a property of a partition of unity

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a topological space and ${\{f_{i}}\}_{i\in I}$ be a partition of unity subordinate to the cover $\{U_{i}\subset M\}_{i\in I}$.
My question: is the set {Supp$(f_{i})\subset M$}$_{i\in I}$ a locally finite cover of $M$ (or a locally finite cover of another specific subset of $M$)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the definition I use this is required. See for example in John Lee's 'Introduction to topological manifolds', chapter 4.

The reason is that you don't want to care about convergence of the sum 
$ \sum\limits_{i\in I} f_i(x) $
at a point $x \in M$.

Comment: Indeed, on some open set containing an arbitrary $x$ ...